# Classification of differential equations as ODE and PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$1. \frac{df}{dx}+\frac{dg}{dy}=f+g$
This isn't ODE since two independent variables are involved.
This should not be PDE (I think) as no partial derivatives are involved.
So in which category this equation comes?
One of my friend told me this is 'system of ODE'. But I am not sure about this as it's just one equation, so calling it system is bit ambiguous I think.

$2. \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{dz}{dx}=K$
This is surely ODE.. but since two dependent variables are involved will it be 'system of ODE'?

$3.$ Consider this equation, $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{dy}{dt}=K$
Firstly,  I am not sure if this is correct equation. Since $y$ is clearly dependent on $x$ as well as $t$, derivatives involved should have been partial. So my first question is if this is valid or not? And if yes, under which DE category it comes?

I believe these are not different questions merged in single one as I am little bit confuse about classification of this equation as ODE or PDE.

Comment: why first is invalid? $f$ is just a function of $x$ and $g$ is just a function of $y$.. so only ordinary derivatives can get involved..

Comment: One can write down equations like $f'(x)+g'(y)=f(x)+g(y)$. Still, as two independent variables are involved, this is a special case of a PDE, with the implicit identities $\partial_yf=0$ and $\partial_xg=0$. Such a situation happens for instance when attempting to find basis solutions as products of scalar functions of the independent variables.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you sir.. can you just check second equation once.. it's ODE right?

Comment: 2) is correct if the functions are scalar. In general, fractions with $d$ are used for derivatives of scalar functions, functions of one scalar argument or the total derivative, while $\partial$ is used for the partial derivatives of multivariate functions. Then there are multiple notations for directional derivatives and the Jacobi matrix of "full" vector functions. // The distinction would not be necessary if always the full and complete argument vector were notated, with different symbols for coordinates and functions. But largely, "abuse of notation" is the rule.

Comment: Got it.. Thank you again